# Easy way to find what item repeated in list

Tags: python, list, loops

So I have list like

```
 l = [1,2,3,4,4]
```

If I make a set obvilously I will get

```
([1,2,3,4])
```

I need a way to find what item repeated in list and was popped out and I do not want to use looping.
If there is an easy way to do so?
I'm using python 2.7

Comment: You can't do this without looping, either explicitly or implicitly. What's your rationale for this restriction?

Comment: Actually no rationale just want to do this with less lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to iterate the list, explicitly or implicitly. One way using standard libraries would be with [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter

In [2]: l = [1,2,3,4,4]

In [3]: Counter(l).most_common(1)[0][0]
Out[3]: 4
```

---

A `Counter` object is a dictionary with elements of some iterable as keys and their respective counts as values:

```
In [4]: Counter(l)
Out[4]: Counter({4: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1})
```

Its [`most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common) method returns a list of items with highest counts:

```
In [5]: Counter(l).most_common()
Out[5]: [(4, 2), (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1)]
```

The optional argument restricts the length of the returned list:

```
In [6]: Counter(l).most_common(1)
Out[6]: [(4, 2)]
```

Comment: looks good, it will be great if you could explain this more detailed. I mean this line `most_common(1)[0][0]`

Comment: @micgeronimo I added a brief explanation and links to the docs